# WorkFlow Management or Business Process Management System

Tags: java, jboss, workflow, jbpm, business-process-management

I am working on project that require workflow management system. I came across two main workflow and BPM engines

1. JBoss's JBPM
2. Apache ODE

Our project's concern is to have activity(Task), forking (Multiple Task) and executing task according to rule evaluation or decision marking.

I am open for any other solution but the criteria is it should be written in JAVA and should be Open Source.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss's JBPM provides a very good configurable support for forking and decision based routing. I have extensively used it. The latest version supports annotation as well. Writing a business flow is a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tarkas for your answer, I am newbie to workflow management. I want to ask one more thing that, can i integrate my existing web application with JBPM ? which is developed in GWT SmartGWT and hibernate, and We have also developed classes for rule engines, Activities and Event and Form generation. Please Help.

Comment: Yes. A simple abstraction of code can get you there. Here is what I would do to convert my exiting application.
1. Abstract out my business logic into different classes (Call them action classes hereon).
2. Create a common datastructure which will flow through these action classes. This the data wrapper which will be used to pass data amongst various action classes.
3. Define sequence of execution (flowchart) of these action classes in JBPM terms. The sequence will contain rule based flow of action classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The founder of jBPM started a new project: http://activiti.org/. You should definitely evaluate it.

It's a modern, open source BPM toolkit in Java, leaded by the founder jBPM, with a more liberal license.

The project is relatively new, but has a lot of "activity" (no pun intended).